# Why does "x*y/z" result in an incorrect negative value?

Tags: java, math

```
System.out.println(1000*16777216/4890);
```

**OUTPUT:** `-82342`

...but should be: `3430923`

How can I fix this?

Comment: That is an positive overflow of the integer value which is the result of your math use `long` instead..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add an `L` to either `1000` or `16777216` (or both)...and that will do the trick.

The reason, like [Rod_Algonquin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3444777/rod-algonquin) stated, it's a *positive overflow of the integer value*, and it's happening when you multiply `1000` by `16777216`; that eventually will be greater than (the max allowed) `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, so it wraps up and starts from `Integer.MIN_VALUE` (in your case the value would be `-402653184`; divide it by `4890` and you will get the unexpected result `-82342`).

Have a look (notice the yellow highlighted section; IDEA will warn you with **Numeric overflow in expression**):

[image]

Comment: Possibly correct, but the OP will probably have no idea why.

Comment: thanks for the explanation I thought there might be an overflow but i did not understand the negative result

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by [@Rod_Algonquin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3444777/rod-algonquin), `1000*16777216` exceeds the [range](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#MIN_VALUE) of `int` (`int` takes value between -2<sup>31</sup> to 2<sup>31</sup> - 1 ), so it causes overflow.

In order to prevent overflow from happening, you can perform the computation using `long` by adding the letter `L` after the number literals like the following:

```
1000L * 16777216 / 4890
```

By default, `1000` is an `int` literal in Java, whereas `1000L` is a `long` literal.

Answer (score 1):

First of all note it's *integer* arithmetic.Whatever the inbetween calculation would be there stored as integer.
`1000*16777216` will give `16777216000` which is out of the range of integer.
So now system tries to manage this integer over flow during runtime.As `16777216000` `>` `Integer.MAX_VALUE` and now it moves for the negative ranged values to handle the overflow..

Try like this `Integer.MAX_VALUE + 1` will give you `-2147483648`.Better way to manage this is to use `long` primitive or you can use `double` for floating point value.